# Want to show data in group using group by

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table where there is composite key of `id` and `emp_no`.

I want to show record of all `tid`s against one `emp_no` like this (not using any aggregate functions because no need to show any thing like that):

```
emp_no   tid
         tid
         tid
emp_no2  tid
         tid
         tid
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT()` in MySQL but consider using a report writer, grid, etc in the front end to to group and format text.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE CONCAT(id,', ',emp_no) = 'id, emp_no'
```

In the above example 'id, emp_no' would be '1, 1' or any combination of id and emp_no.

Where does tid come from by the way you only mention `emp_no` and `id`